# Fixed $h> 0$, which functions $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(x) = \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$?

Tags: real-analysis, recurrence-relations, functional-equations

Consider $h>0$, I would like to know what are the functions $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that satisfy the following relation

$$f(x) = \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}. $$

**NB:** 
I do not even have the guarantee of the continuity of $f$.

---

The only thing that concludes was that $$f(x) = \frac{f(x + nh)}{(1+h)^n}, $$
but I do not find it useful.

Comment: Not useful? You pretty much have the formula for $f$. :D Just note that $f(x+nh)=(1+h)^n f(x)$ and thus $f$ only depends on values on $[0, h)$ which can be arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: note that the value $f(x)$ lets us determine all the values $f(x+k \cdot h)$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and doesn't affect any other value. Consider the equivalence relation ${\sim} \subseteq \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$

$$x \sim y \iff x-y = k \cdot h \text{ for some } k \in \mathbb{Z}.$$

Finding a function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying the given equation is equivalent to finding $f \upharpoonright [x]_{\sim}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ separately and then combining them into one function $: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I think  this solves the problem. I was expecting some closed form, 
but judging by your hint, it is clear that the points between $[0,h)$ have no rule of determination

Comment: @MatheusManzatto That's right, the mapping $f \mapsto f \upharpoonright [0, h) $ is a natural bijection between the set of all solutions of the equation and the set of all functions $[0, h) \to \mathbb{R}$.